# Multiple inputs with same name in struts

Tags: html, struts, struts-1

I have a form with a field that may have zero to multiple values for the named field, e.g.,:

```
<form ...>
<input type="hidden" name="browseId[]" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="browseId[]" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="browseId[]" value="8">
<input type="hidden" name="browseId[]" value="10">

<input type="text" name="browseId[]">
...
</form>
```

I do not seem to be able to get the variable `browseId` as an array, which is standard operating procedure in HTML, other languages, and I'm stumped. I'm actually first processing the form output in a validation method, using a DynaActionForm:

```
public static ActionMessages validatePlacement(DynaActionForm form) {
    String[] rootBrowseIds = (String []) form.get("browseId");
    ...
}
```

Here's the form bean and action definition in struts-config.xml:

```
<form-bean name="placementForm" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
    <!-- I've tried a few variations -->
    <!--<form-property name="browseId" type="java.lang.String"/>-->
    <!--<form-property name="browseIds" type="java.lang.String[]"/>-->
    <form-property name="browseId" type="java.lang.String[]"/>
    ...
</form-bean>

...

<action path="/admin/editPlacement"
        type="com.rc.mexp.action.admin.placementinventory.EditPlacementAction"
        name="placementForm">
    <forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/pages/admin/placement/placementEdit.jsp"/>
    <forward name="error" path="/admin/managePlacementInventory.do"/>
</action>
```

It appears that only the last value, empty in this case, is being received by Struts. WTF?

Any ideas?

Is there a way to change my form-bean definition to include something like this? I'm not allowed to use the `<` and `>` characters inside the type:

```
<form-property name="browseId" type="java.util.Map<java.lang.String[]>"/>
```

Other stackoverflow Qs that I examined already:
[retrieve multiple inputs of the same name from jsp to struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314787/retrieve-multiple-inputs-of-the-same-name-from-jsp-to-struts) (does not seem relevant)
[Multiple inputs with same name through POST in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php)
[Struts 2 - pattern/strategy for multiple objects on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820447/struts-2-pattern-strategy-for-multiple-objects-on-the-same-page)

Comment: How are a PHP and Struts 2 post relevant?

Comment: Also, what version of Struts?

Comment: I'm looking for how to get multiple inputs, I looked at everything that seemed remotely on point. Also, check my tags, I spec'd struts 1.

Comment: There are different versions of Struts 1. I don't see any reason to not be specific; why should I test in 1.2.9 if you're running 1.3.8?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize it made a big difference. 1.2.7 (it's not entirely my call to upgrade)

Comment: It may or may not, depends on the functionality--just easier to target an answer if the version is known. 1.2 -> 1.3 introduced some underlying implementation changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the form field incorrectly, you should be using `getStrings("browseId")` since you're trying to get multiple strings.

Your code won't even compile for me, I'm not sure why you don't get a class cast exception.

Comment: @kewpiedoll99 Oh, never mind; you're using `get`, not `getString`. Why aren't you using `getStrings`? This all works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks - getStrings("browseId") worked. (I didn't know about it.)

Comment: @kewpiedoll99 Cool; glad you got it working. (I had to look it up myself; couldn't remember--been a loooong time since I did anything in Struts 1; hope you're being forced to use it instead of choosing it!)